# Display shared/featured projects

Tags: read-the-docs

I have a local readthedocs build serving documentation for a number of projects (on a private corporate network). Each developer can create their own project, but I need the generated docs to be visible to all users - whether signed in or not.
The public readthedocs has a "Featured Projects" section on the landing page, but I can't find anywhere enable this feature in the configuration.